# how to center align an image inside the JavaScript Image Slider

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, image-scaling

i have created a slide show with JavaScript ,the resolution set for the frame is 960x540 but when i insert images into the slider it align automatically to the left,how can i align the image inside the slider to the center,and is there any way to automatically align the images even if the images are not exactly the resolution of the slider.This is the basic code i used.

```
 <style type="text/css">

#sliderFrame {position:relative;width:960px;margin: 0 auto 40px;}

#slider {
    width:960px;height:540px;/* Make it the same size as your images */
 background:#fff url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-aVGCcclfKQo/UR-T3vxFAMI/AAAAAAAABm8/ncwIfUdoLIw/s1600/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;/*make the image slider center-aligned */
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}
#slider img {
 position:absolute;
 border:none;
 display:none;
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped in a link) */
#slider a.imgLink {
 z-index:2;
 display:none;position:absolute;
 top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
 width:100%;height:100%;
}

/* Caption styles */
div.mc-caption-bg, div.mc-caption-bg2 {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 padding:0;
 left:0px; 
 bottom:15px;
 z-index:3;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-size: 0;
}
div.mc-caption-bg {
 background-color:black;
}
div.mc-caption {
 font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
 color:#EEE;
 z-index:4;
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align:center;
}
div.mc-caption a {
 color:#FB0;
}
div.mc-caption a:hover {
 color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
div.navBulletsWrapper  {
 top:500px; left:280px; /* Its position is relative to the #slider */
 width:150px;
 background:none;
 padding-left:20px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:5;
 cursor:pointer;
}

/* each bullet */
div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:11px; height:11px;
    background:transparent url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZUaX5-lcCi4/UR-TzMXcpuI/AAAAAAAABm0/kokxtfFdNcU/s1600/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:11px;/* distance between each bullet*/
    _position:relative;/*IE6 hack*/
}
div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -11px;}
.intro {
    bottom: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}
/* --------- Others ------- */
#slider 
{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
</style>
<script src="http://project.dimpost.com/image-slider/js-image-slider-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://project.dimpost.com/image-slider/js-image-slider-2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can add

```
left: 50%;
```

to your CSS rule with "#slider img" selector and add some JavaScript to set negative margin to the images that equals half of the image width, for example (using jQuery):

```
$("#slider img").each(function () {
    $(this).css("margin-left", -this.width / 2);
})
```

Comment: hi,thank you for the reply,i am using blogger so will this for for it, i am not that good in programming,i depend mostly on trial and error method,so can instruct me were to paste these codes so that i don't have to mess with my site ,also can you suggest a code to automatically resize image according to the size..currently i am re sizing each image using Photoshop to make 960x540 before using in the slider,which is very time consuming,is there any way to avoid that..

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using a blogging tool like Wordpress, but if you are, perhaps you should search for some plugins, I believe there should be plugins for image sliders and for image resizing, and as I understand they don't require you to be a programmer to install and use them.

Comment: I am using blogger,The plugin available for the blogger doesn't look good,i have been using the slide show from photosnack which is an external website which provide slide show which we can embed on the page..but recently i come to know they have limit for the maximum viewers per day ,so i cant stick with it any more that's why i was looking for alternatives,i have managed get this slide show working the only issue left is the resizing,which i can manage with photoshop if there is no other solution

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't worked with blogger so I'm afraid I cannot help you here. Perhaps you should clarify your question or ask a new one specifying that you use blogger etc.